# How to make sure that size of the image is below 100kb using imagejpeg()

Tags: php

I am uploading products images and want to make sure everything below 100kb so I took reference and write this , problem is that in some cases size is above 100kb , how to choose a value such that size is always below 100kb

```
function compress($source, $destination, $quality) {

    $info = getimagesize($source);

    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);

    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

    imagejpeg($image, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/image processing/'.$destination, $quality);

    
}

$source_img = 'product.jpg';
$destination_img = 'destination.jpg';

compress($source_img, $destination_img, 70);
```

Comment: Dimensions and quality should be the important factors, no? The file size is a function of that. Are the images all the same dimensions and quality and yet the file sizes differ? Or are some images simply larger than others? Then resize them to the same sizes.

Comment: @deceze images are different dimensions but most of them are a square 600*600

Comment: @deceze is there any method to predict size of image , because when the image is taken in a portrait mode then even a factor 20 does'nt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to have a restriction for image size. Do not allow to upload images more than 2M for example or more. You can do this easily.

For compressing the images one way is changing the width and quality of the image.

the following function for instance can do this for you.

```
     function create_thumbnail($file, $pathToSave = '', $w, $quality = 95, $crop = FALSE)
    {
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
        $h = $height * ($w / $width);
        $new_height = $h;
        $r = $width / $height;
        if ($crop) {
            if ($width > $height) {
                $width = ceil($width - ($width * abs($r - $w / $h)));
            } else {
                $height = ceil($height - ($height * abs($r - $w / $h)));
            }
            $newwidth = $w;
            $newheight = $h;
        } else {
            if ($w / $h > $r) {
                $newwidth = $h * $r;
                $newheight = $h;
            } else {
                $newheight = $w / $r;
                $newwidth = $w;
            }
        }
        $what = getimagesize($file);
        switch (strtolower($what['mime'])) {
            case 'image/png':
                $src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
                break;
            case 'image/jpeg':
                $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                break;
            case 'image/gif':
                $src = imagecreatefromgif($file);
                break;
            default:
        }
        if ($new_height != '') {
            $newheight = $new_height;
        }
        $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);//the new image
        imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
        imagejpeg($dst, $pathToSave, $quality);
        return $dst;
    }
```

w is new width set for example 500.(create new image with 500px width)

Comment: Thanking you and @deceze for telling me that file dimension is critical , I did the similar but with using `imagescale()` and not `imagecopyresampled()` and copying this new image over a white dummy square image , things look good now.

Answer (score 0):

> 1MB == 1048576 bytes

```
If you want to restrict file uploads to below < 1MB only!! then, since the $_FILES array, will output in bytes you can do the following.

if($_FILES['name']['size'] > 1048576){
  //You can not upload this file
}
```

> Or you want want to restrict it from browser-level, you can add an attribute to your form as

```
form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1048576" />
    <input type="file" name="pictures" />
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

> Offcourse, the second option can be changed by anyone easily, and
> should never be used.

Comment: I don't want to restrict I want to compress the size

Comment: Create a compressImage() function to compress JPEG, PNG, and GIF images.

The function takes 3 parameters –
1. Source
2. Destination
3. File quality

Call imagecreatefromjpeg($source), imagecreatefromgif($source), and imagecreatefrompng($source) to create new image according to $info['mime'] value.

Execute imagejpeg() method to store image to the destination. Here, the third parameter quality is optional. It takes value from 0 – 100 and the default value is 75.

Comment: compressImage($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'],$location,60);